# Best approach to encrypt username/password and then transfer them to the server in Java application

Tags: java, encryption

What is the best approach to encrypt password entered by user at client side and the decrypt at the server in an Java application.?

Basically I want to make sure all data entered by client is secure.

Regards
Tarun Sapra

Comment: There's a difference between wanting to secure the username and password and securing all data, can you please clarify which you're asking?

Comment: SSL. HTTPS is secure and encrypted. Transport layer security is language agnostic. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure

Answer (score 5):

Use SSL. It solves all your problems.

If you can't use SSL for some reason then you might need to post some more information about your system so we can provide more specific advice.

Comment: @FearUs: SSL is only 3 keystrokes :)

Comment: Yep, by the time I typed Ctrl+T and SSL to get Wikipedia's SSL link, you clicked "Add Comment" ... :D

Comment: how to implement SSL and HTTPS @Cameron

Comment: @Deepak: Depends on your system. For browser-based things just change your URL from http:// to https:// and make sure your server supports SSL. For other kinds of system it's a little more complex and probably beyond the scope of a comment. There's plenty of documentation out there on how to use SSL.

Answer (score 1):

This depends greatly on the specifics of your system.  One common, and well supported option, would be to just use SSL to encrypt everything going over the wire.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use ssl because of costs, installing it etc then you could try [this](http://schneimi.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/aes-128bit-encryption-between-java-and-php/)

Comment: what costs? And what about the key staleness problem?